# Div floating to the side as screen gets larger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:** Inner Div (i.e. `.service-header-box`) is floating away from the rest of the content layout.

Content Layout Looks like this (Basic Visual):

```
<Article>

<entry-header>
  <figure> background image
   <service-header-box> with content </>
  </>
</>

<content-width-wrapper> Main Content </>

</Article>
```

I have a page, it has an `.entry-header` div which has a full bleed background image. And inner div with content in it named `.service-header-box.`. The `.service-header-box.`is floating away in 3500px+ screen size from .content-width-wrapper div instead of being vertical aligned with it.

Here is a screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHqCj.jpg

```css
/* ## Service Page (Page.php) */

.page .site-content {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#page-header-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.service-full-bleed {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  height: 370px;
}

.page .service-full-bleed.yes-service-header p {
  color: #000000;
}


/* Service Page Feature Header container */

.service-header-box {
  max-width: 1084px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.service-header-box .entry-title {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
}

.page .service-full-bleed.yes-service-header .header-desc {
  color: #000000;
  width: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}

UPDATED: CSS CONTENT CONTAINER

.content-width-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: auto;
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 2rem;
 }

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) {
 .content-width-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: auto;
 }
 .has-page-sidebar .content-width-wrapper {
  justify-content: space-around;
 }

  .no-page-sidebar .content-width-wrapper {
   justify-content: flex-start;
 }
}
```

```html
<article id="post-84" class="post-84 page type-page status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">
  <header class="entry-header">
    <figure class="service-full-bleed yes-service-header" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/other2.jpg)">
      <div class="service-header-box">
        <h2 class="entry-title">About</h2>
        <!-- Header Image In Service Page - Full bleed -->
        <div class="header-desc">
          <p>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point, sometimes on purpose (injected humouretimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). etimes on purpose (injected
            humour.
          </p>
        </div>


      </div>
    </figure>
  </header>
  <!-- .entry-header -->

  <div class="content-width-wrapper">
    <div class="entry-content post-content">
      <h5>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</h5>
      <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.”</p>


    </div>
    <!-- .entry-content .post-content -->


    <!-- div-->

  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing styles for `.content-width-wrapper`, `.entry-content` or  `.post-content` i.e. the content area. It would be helpful to see a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, just added the content-width-wrapper css in the file. That mostly has the layout defined

Comment: You want the about to come left or the contents to go to the centre??

Answer (score 0):

Style `margin : auto` is used to horizontally center align the element within its container.

Removing `margin: auto` from `.service-header-box` ensures that the content of `service-header-box` is LEFT aligned irrespective of the size of the page viewed in browser.

```
/* Service Page Feature Header container */

.service-header-box {
  max-width: 1084px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header content (`.service-header-box`) and your main content (`.content-width-wrapper`) have different `max-width` values. The main content has a wider `max-width`, so it keeps expanding after the header reaches its maximum width.

To fix this, I suggest you give them the same `max-width`:

```
.service-header-box {
  max-width: 1400px; // rather than 1084px
}

.content-width-wrapper {
    max-width: 1400px;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete the padding on .service-full-bleed, or put the same padding on the wrapper

**EDIT**

If you still want the max-width of the wrapper to be 1400px and service-header-box to be 1080px, then do that

```
<style>
  .service-header-box{
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .service-header-box-content{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1080px;
  }
</style>
<div class="service-header-box">
  <div class="service-header-box-content">
      <h2 class="entry-title">About</h2>
      <!-- Header Image In Service Page - Full bleed -->
      <div class="header-desc">
        <p>
          It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point, sometimes on purpose (injected humouretimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). etimes on purpose (injected
            humour.
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For people that experienced the same issue but with the same width for the two elements, if you have the property box-sizing: border-box applied on every element (it's a common use case) the padding will be your problem. It's the reason of my first answer, before you put additional informations on your width

Comment: have tried, still not aligned to the content wrapper div

Comment: This can't fix the issue

Comment: You didn't specify that your wrapper had a max-width of 1400px, I just try to answer based on the informations you provided.